# coreplot: Right scroll does not really work

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot, swipe

I'm using core plot and have allowed user interactions. Now it is possible to scroll in all directions using gestures. All directions? No, if the finger is moving from left to right (so I try to scroll from 100 to 0) sometimes nothing or much less than usually expected happens.
So if I scroll in the opposite direction, the same point remains under my finger. If I scroll from left to right, there is much less movement.

I have no idea, where the problem can be. Expecially, since I also tried to implement scrolling by swiping (My own Swiping-Implementation, not the Coreplot implementation) and the result was almost the same: All swipes worked, only right-swipe made trouble.

Well, I have an idea: Right-Swipe is already implemented somehow in the CorePlot-library to do something else, and the gesture is recognized to do something else than desired. ... but I found nothing about it.

Ideas?

Comment: There's nothing in Core Plot that should favor one scroll direction over another. Does this happen on both the simulator and a device? Do you have a plot space delegate monitoring changes that might be doing more calculations or causing more significant side effects when scrolling in one direction?

Comment: I have removed every possible reason I could imagine, which could effect this behaviour. There is no other gesture (no swiping, no tapping, nothing...) in this app.

The strange thing is, before I used self-implemented swipes for all directions, I deleted them.
I tried it on two IPads.